# Java Script - Most Effective Way To Set Value Of An Input Field

Tags: javascript

I've got a short question colegues! Here it is: is this the fastest script way to change the input field's value when some of the 3 buttons are clicked? Here is the script:

```
<form  name="viewtype" action="javascript:alert(document.viewtype.option.value);">

     <input name="option" type="hidden" value="" />

     <input name="" type="button" onclick="document.viewtype.option.value='0';"/>
     <input name="" type="button" onclick="document.viewtype.option.value='1';"/>
     <input name="" type="button" onclick="document.viewtype.option.value='2';"/>

     <input name="" type="submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: If it wasn't, would it make a huge difference?

Comment: I understand that it is not important for u, but for me it's very. The reason is why i have a huje amount of other javascript in the web page which enough slows down the browser performens, so each best practise in doing that is strongly important for me. Although, thanks for the opinion :)

Comment: If your app is slow, you should spend time with profiling tools to figure out why it's slow - I doubt it's because of the code above.

Comment: Setting the value of a single field in response to a button click is not going to be slow unless you're doing something really strange. Your page must be slow for other reasons. I'm not a big fan of the `document.elementname` syntax, because it can cause you problems if your element names are the same as "standard" `document` object properties. So even though it works in most cases I think you're better off using `document.getElementById()` instead.

Comment: P.S. Are you looking for "most effective" as in your question title, or "fastest" as in your question body?

Comment: Do you mean performance-wise or simplest implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like so:

HTML:

```
<form  name="viewtype">
     <input type="hidden" name="option">
     <input type="button" value="0">
     <input type="button" value="1">
     <input type="button" value="2">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = document.forms.viewtype,
    buttons = form.querySelectorAll( '[type="button"]' );

[].forEach.call( buttons, function ( button ) {
    button.onclick = function () {
        form.elements.option.value = this.value;
    };
});

form.onsubmit = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( this.elements.option.value );
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9B7du/1/